# .js page doesn't accept hashed password from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, authentication, hash

This is the manager.js file where I enter password in the 'util.createHash("password")' field and get the hashed key from 'localhost/manager/hash'. Then I add the hashed password to the 'ra_password' field in the sql database that I have created.

**manager.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var async = require('async');

var util = require('../utils/util');
var db = require('../utils/database');
var connection = db.connection();

router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  if (req.session.manager) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }

  if (req.query.tip == 'error') {
    var tip = 'username or password incorrect!';
  } else {
    var tip = null;
  }
  res.render('login', { tip: tip });
});

router.get('/hash', function(req,res){
    res.end(util.createHash("password")); **//I enter pwd here for Hash**
});

router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM restaurant_accounts WHERE ra_name=?';
  connection.query(sql, [username], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result.length == 0) {
      return res.redirect('/manager/login?tip=error');
    } 
    var account = result[0];
    if (!util.checkHash(password, account.ra_password)) {
      return res.redirect('/manager/login?tip=error');
    }

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE rest_owner_id=?', [account.ra_id], function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var restaurant = result[0];
      req.session.manager = {
        id: account.ra_id,
        name: account.ra_name,
        rest_id: restaurant.rest_id,
        rest_name: restaurant.rest_name
      };
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
});

router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/manager/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

But when I use that password to login to the "localhost/manager/login" page it doesn't accept the password and says "username or password incorrect!". Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you rehashing the password when you try to login? You have to compare two hashes, not the plaintext password to a hash.

Comment: @MikeC No, I'm not comparing a plain text pwd to a hash. I create a hash password first using a plain text and enter the hashed password in the 'ra_password' field and use the plain text again to login. But it doesn't accept the password.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. I see that you're *saving* a hash but are you converting the password to a hash *when you login?* You have to convert the password to a hash in both places.

Comment: @MikeC You mean the password that I use in the actual login page? The login page is the same manager.js file as above, how do I check that?